# Compare differences between two tables using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
const firstTable = document.getElementById('table_1')
const secondTable = document.getElementById('table_2')

const rows1 = firstTable.rows
const rows2 = secondTable.rows

for (let i = 0; i < rows1.length; i++) {
  for (let x in rows1[i].cells) {
    let col = rows1[i].cells[x]
    console.log(col)

  }
  for (let j = 0; j < rows2.length; j++) {


  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="table_1">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>per</td>
    <td style="background-color:red">27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>notexist</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table_2">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>per</td>
    <td style="background-color:green">25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>alex</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to compare these two tables dynamically in javascript to get the result like the tables I put in the code. I need to compare every cell in every row if ids are equal. If id doesn't exist in the second table I need to write this not exist. For example, I put age in the first row of the first table not equal age in the second row of the second table. If Not equal, style background color to red or green.

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your question?

Comment: You need to write a custom function. I would prefer that you start by thinking logically of how would this problem be solved, building an algorithm, shaping it into code parallelly, and then if you get stuck at a specific point, browse/ask SO.

Comment: "*Compare these 2 tables so they appear like the result*" - there's only 2 tables, which is the "result"?  How do you decide if it's red or green?

Comment: Are you building these tables in the first place? If you have the data before it's turned into HTML mark-up it would probably be better to do your comparison on those data structures instead.

Comment: I need to compare these two tables dynamically in javascript to get the result like the tables i created in code. I have these tow tabels in html and i need to compare between them in javascript. evrey cell in first table with cell in second tabel.

Comment: `const firstArr = [
{id: 1,name: 'Per', age: 27}
{id: 2,name: 'Tom', age: 25}
]
const secondArr = [
{id: 1,name: 'Per', age: 25}
{id: 2,name: 'Tom', age: 25}
{id: 3,name: 'Tom', age: 25}
]` I created these tow tabels from these arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the DOM `table`, if they are identical(structure), you can make a loop on the `TD`s of one of them and compare `textContent` to the other standing at the same position:

here is an example

```js
const firstTable = document.querySelectorAll("#table1 td");
const secondTable = document.querySelectorAll("#table2 td");

// loop on one of the table if both are of identical structure, else it is pointless
for (let i = 0; i < firstTable.length; i++) {
  if (firstTable[i].textContent !== secondTable[i].textContent) {
    firstTable[i].classList.add('redbg');// here do what you need to when not equal
  }
  // else { /* do what you need to if equal*/ }
}
```

```css
.redbg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>per</td>
    <td>27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>notexist</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>per</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Tom</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>alex</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

from your array, idea can be the same loop on the first one and check if firstone and second got the same content at the same position, and add the class while building the table.

Comment: Thank you very match.

Comment: one thenk. for exambel if Alex in second table no exist in first table. how to to add empty row in first table.

Comment: You can test the other way round if you wish `if(){} else{}`  is where you can decide something, however, the script here do not see any rows, just position  inside an array. @raw